# Как добавить кнопку на панель браузера через JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как при помощи JavaScript добавить кнопку на панель браузера, по нажатию на которую будет выполнять JavaScript код на любом открытом в данный момент сайте?
Надо создавать `userscript`?
Как через него добавить такую кнопку на панель?

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо смотреть в сторону расширений браузера.

Стандартный клиентский JavaScript не позволяет добавлять кнопки на панель браузера и вообще как-то влиять на поведение самого браузера, так как исполняется в защищённой среде, и разработчики браузера не могут позволить страницам сайта влиять на работу самого браузера.

Но такая функциональность делается на основе расширений браузера, правда для каждого браузера придётся писать своё расширение.

Почитать по поводу написания расширений для хром можно например [тут](https://canonium.com/articles/briefly-about-building-a-chrome-extension).

Кроме того можно посмотреть в сторону JavaScript клиентских скриптов через [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net), это расширение для разных браузеров которое позволяет запускать кастомные скрипты на сайтах, правда не уверен что можно запуск скрипта вынести в отдельную кнопку, зато думаю можно подвесить на хоткей, если скрипт инджектить на каждый сайт. Или запускать через интерфейс самого Tampermonkey.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Артём если ответ вам подходит, отметьте его пожалуйста ответом.